# How to add attribute on each blazor component automatically by rule?

Tags: html, blazor

For testing purpouses I want to have custom attribute on each, for example, button each page of my app without any manual adding.

Let's say I have page:

```
@page "/mypage"

<h1>This is page</h1>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">NO, click ME</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

and, eventually, after some kind of additional rendering step, I want to see this html in my browser:

```
<h1>This is page</h1>

<button class="btn btn-primary" my-custom-attribute="button-click-me">Click me</button>

<button class="btn btn-primary" my-custom-attribute="button-no-click-me">NO, click ME</button>
```

So, the rule for makeing `my-custom-attribute` content comes from component content itself. It can be described as "component name + dash + text from component to lower case" => `button(component name)` + `-` + `click-me(text from component to lower case with dashes instead spaces)`. Rule should be described somewhere in C# code and should "targeting" on list of components(buttons, divs, etc).

Is there any way to achieve that? Maybe there is a way to tweak Blazor rendering process somehow?

Comment: The simplest solution would be to create a custom button component with whatever common attributes and initialization that is required.

Comment: Honestly, I need this attribute for many elements, not only buttons :) Maybe even for almost all elements. So new custom components is not my solution.

Comment: Understood.  There are ways you might do this, but more information is needed. You say you do not want to add these attributes manually.  Yet, if they are automatically added, what determines the value of the attribute? For example, you want to see "button-no-click-me", but where would that come from?

Comment: Where does the value in the custom attribute come from (how is it populated)?   What's it's purpose?  The answer probably is a generic custom component, but without more information ?????

Comment: My bad, thought it's kinda obvious. Updated my question.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis basically, purpouse is to add custom attributes to easy access to elements in Cypress tests.

Answer (score 0):

I can see no other solution than using a custom generic component.  Someone may come up with a better answer.  If so, I'll happily delete this one.

Here's a basic custom component to render html elements:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering;

namespace BlazorApp1.Pages
{
    public class MyComponentBase : ComponentBase
    {
        [Parameter] [EditorRequired] public string Tag { get; set; } = "div";

        [Parameter] public string MyAttributeValue { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [Parameter] public string? Content { get; set; }

        [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

        [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)] public IDictionary<string, object> UserAttributes { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        private string myAttribute => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Content) ? this.MyAttributeValue : this.Content.Replace(" ", "-");

        protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.OpenElement(0, Tag);
            builder.AddMultipleAttributes(1, UserAttributes);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.myAttribute))
                builder.AddAttribute(2, "my-attribute", this.myAttribute);

            if (ChildContent is not null)
                builder.AddContent(3, ChildContent);
            else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Content))
                builder.AddMarkupContent(4, Content);

            builder.CloseElement();
        }
    }
}
```

And a Demo:

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<MyComponentBase Tag="button" MyAttribute="Blazor-Component" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.OnClick Content="My Blazor Button" />

<MyComponentBase Tag="div" MyAttributeValue="Survey-Prompt-Div" class="m-2">
    <SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
</MyComponentBase>

<div>
    @this.message
</div>
@code {
    private string message = string.Empty;

    private void OnClick()
    {
        this.message = $"Hello Blazor at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()} ";
    }
}
```

While this sort of works, it highlights some issues with what you are trying to do.

1. You can't just get the "content" between the opening and closing tags of an element.  The content is a `RenderFragment`, not a string that you can parse and use for your attribute.  Therefore anything like the second block in the example requires a manual setting of the attribute (you may as well define it directly!).
2. The complexity of the component depends on what type of content you want to apply your attribute to.

Anyway, the component demonstrates the basic principles of how to capture parameters and attributes and use them to construct elements.

Comment: Alright, that looks fine. But what if I want to put this attribute in components that I can't create like that? For example, some kind of standart calendar view that I want to test but don't want to make my own implementation to be able to inherit it form `MyComponentBase`?
I mean it works for simple things like buttons but can't I "tweak" default rendering behaviour without `MyComponentBase`?